# Convert matlab code with function handle to python

Tags: python, matlab

I have this matlab code. I dont know, how it can be rewritten to Python, since I dont know mmatlab that well.

```
function tf = funf(f, g, h, n)
  for i=1:3
  tf(i) = f + g + h + n
end
end

Rexp = [0 10 20]

Cost=@(GT) sum( ( funf(GT( 1 ),GT( 2 ),GT( 3 ),GT( 4 ))./Rexp-1 ).^2);
```

`Cost` function is used in `fmincon` optimizer.

Can anyone explain me, what `@(GT)` does and how to rewrite this code? I wanted to use this with `scipy` `optimize.fmin` instead.

Comment: `@(GT)` defines an anonymous function of the variable `GT`. For example, `@(GT) sum(GT)` in Matlab would translate to `lambda GT: sum(GT)` in Python

Comment: @LuisMendo And what is the parameter eg. `GT( 1 )`?

Comment: That's indexing into the array (vector?) `GT`. `GT(1)` in Matlab corresponds to `GT[0]` in Python